# Bulk API contacts not showing up in the sales force interface

Tags: bulk-api

I have used bulk API to create contacts and I got confirmation that job has successfully created and and data processed.

I also got following information when I try to check result of bulk process, but problem is this contacts not showing up in my developer edition's database.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
    <result>
        <id>0030Y00000KJooaQAD</id>
        <success>true</success>
        <created>true</created>
    </result>
    <result>
        <id>0030Y00000KJoobQAD</id>
        <success>true</success>
        <created>true</created>
    </result>
</results>
```

Comment: Running a soql query from the developers console with those ids as the filter gives you no results?

Comment: Thanks for the update , this my first day on salesforce can you pass an URL and instructions to fetch the information based on the id?

Comment: Check [this trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/developer_console), the [last section](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/developer_console/units/developer_console_queries) is a "how-to" on queries. If you're new to salesforce, I'd also recommend trying some of the other trailheads, its a great way to try features without using your production org.

Comment: Thanks , when I used quey editor I could find that the contacts I have created , the interface is also reflected after 4-5 hours. I also done some more tests found. Some times interface is updating immediately but sometimes not. However when using query editor I can immediately see the contacts created/updated